# List view cannot get user info from session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have created in my login form a session which is UsrNme to get the user name. It binds all the listviews and gridviews in the user panel page depending on the UsrNme Session. If the current user logs in with his username it will work normally, but in the registration form after a new user registers, the page shows nothing, even the user name. I have created another session in the registration form to collect the information of the user and bind the listviews depending on the new user name but it doesn't work.

Here is login form codebehind:

```
protected void Loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection log = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    log.Open();
    string checkuser = "Select count(*) from UserInfo where UID='" + usrnamlogintxtbx.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, log);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); 
    log.Close();

    if (temp == 1)
    {
        log.Open();
        string checkpasswordquery = "Select Password from UserInfo where  UID='" + usrnamlogintxtbx.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand passcom = new SqlCommand(checkpasswordquery, log);
        string password = passcom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");

        if (password == usrnamloginpassbx.Text)
        {
            Session["UsrNme"] = usrnamlogintxtbx.Text;
            Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");
        } 
        else
        {
            passwronglbl.Text = "Password is incorrect";
        }
    } 
    else
    { 
        wronglogusernamelbl.Text = "Invalid User Name";
    } 
}
```

Here is the registration form:

```
string sc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable countrycascd = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adaptar = new SqlDataAdapter("select [countryID],[country] FROM [countr]", con);
            adaptar.Fill(countrycascd);

            countrdrdolst.DataSource = countrycascd;
            countrdrdolst.DataTextField = "country";
            countrdrdolst.DataValueField = "countryID";
            countrdrdolst.DataBind();
        } 
        countrdrdolst.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Välj land", "0"));
    }
} 

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    string sqlstatment = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (UID, FN, LN, Password, RePass, Email,Country, State,City, Post, Img, Logo,RegDate) VALUES (@UID,@FN,@LN,@Password,@RePass,@Email,@Country,@State,@City,@Post,@Img,@Logo,@RegDate)";

    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = sqlstatment;

    //Insert the parameters first
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", fnbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", lnamebox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passtxtbx1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RePass", passtxtbx2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", countrdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", statedrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citiesdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", postbox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", persimgFileUpload1.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Logo", logoFileUpload.FileName);

    //Get the Current Date Time here
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegDate", DateTime.Now);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UsrNme.Text))
    {
        Lblcheckusername.Text = "User Name Already Exist";
        Lblcheckusername.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        Lblcheckusername.Text = "User Name Available";
        Lblcheckusername.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    } 
    if (persimgFileUpload1.HasFile)
    { 
        persimgFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/users/" + persimgFileUpload1.FileName)); 
    } 
    if (logoFileUpload.HasFile)
    { 
        logoFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/Logos/" + logoFileUpload.FileName)); 
    } 
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
    ad.Fill(ds);
    Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");
} 

protected void UsrNme_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UsrNmeReg"] = UsrNme.Text;
}
```

Here is the user panel codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UsrNme"] != null)
    {
        USRNMElbl.Text = Session["UsrNme"].ToString();

        using (SqlConnection userlistview = new SqlConnection(sc))
        {
            // Open your connection
            userlistview.Open();

            // Build your data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter userinfoDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [UserInfo] WHERE ([UID] = @UID)", sc);

            // Grab your location (guaranteed to exist from the above if-statement
            string UsrNme = Convert.ToString(Session["UsrNme"]);

            // Add your parameters to your data adapter
            userinfoDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme);

            // Define your data set
            DataSet userinfods = new DataSet();

            // Fill your data set
            userinfoDA.Fill(userinfods);

            // Bind your results
            userinfo.DataSource = userinfods.Tables[0];
            userinfo.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}


protected void addadsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    string sqlstatment = "INSERT INTO [ads] ([Section], [Category], [UID], [AdsTit], [AdsDesc], [Country], [State], [City], [AdsPrice], [Img1], [img2], [img3], [img4], [img5], [Wtags]) VALUES (@Section, @Category, @UID, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State, @City, @AdsPrice, @Img1, @img2, @img3, @img4, @img5, @Wtags)";

    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = sqlstatment;

    //Insert the parameters first
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Catedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", SubCatedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", USRNMElbl.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsDesc", Editor1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", countrdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", statedrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citiesdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsPrice", adsaddpristxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", FileUpload1.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img2", FileUploadImg2.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img3", FileUploadImg3.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img4", FileUploadImg4.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img5", FileUploadImg5.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wtags", addadswtagtxtbtn.Text);

    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
    ad.Fill(ds);

    Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");
}
```

Comment: try not to put unnecessary code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood your problem right.
In your registration page you have this code, which sets the user name in the session. But why to you have "UsrNmeReg" instead of "UsrNme"?. This is the session key that you are refering in your user panel code.

```
protected void UsrNme_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UsrNmeReg"] = UsrNme.Text;
}
```

I think you need to call the following line of code, in the btnSave_Click event before redirecting to the user panel page

```
Session["UsrNme"] =  UsrNme.Text
```